# JSON object in for loop keeps only last record

Tags: json, for-loop

I have this code

```
JSONObject output = new JSONObject();
JSONObject elements = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArrayOutput = new JSONArray(); 
ArrayList<String> name = ArrayList<String>();

for (int i=0 ; i<name.size() ; i++){

    elements.put("Name", name.get(i));
    jsonArrrayOutput.put(elements);
}


output.put("Results", jsonArrrayOutput).toString();
```

The problem is that the resulted output Json has only the last element of "name" arraylist many times, not all elements. 
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding elements again same name key in `jsonArrayOutput` 
try creating a new JSONObject for each iteration.
E.g.:

```
JSONObject output = new JSONObject();
JSONObject elements = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArrayOutput = new JSONArray(); 
ArrayList<String> name = ArrayList<String>();

for (int i=0 ; i<name.size() ; i++){

    JSONObject temp = new JSONObject();
    temp.put("Name", name.get(i));
    jsonArrrayOutput.put(temp);
}


output.put("Results", jsonArrrayOutput).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of your code. The problem with your code is the declaration of your `elements` object. Whenever you changed the `elements` that would change the `element` and the `element` that you added to the array.

This happens because reference is used when you put the `element` object into the `jsonArrayOutput`

```
JSONObject output = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArrayOutput = new JSONArray();
ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
     JSONObject elements = new JSONObject();
     try {
          elements.put("Name", name.get(i));
          jsonArrayOutput.put(elements);
     } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

try {
    output.put("Results", jsonArrayOutput).toString();
    Log.i("info",output.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope that helps!